# Pattern for creating "view objects"

Tags: python, object, oop, design-patterns

Is there any recommended pattern for creating custom "view objects" in Python, through which other objects can be viewed, but not modified? Like the [view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) that `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()`, and `dict.items()` return.

In particular, I am wondering if a view object `v` for an object `o` should contain (a reference to) `o`, or just detached methods of `o`, if a view object for a given object `o` should be unique and be a part of `o`, how the class of views of objects of class `C` should be related to `C`...

*Update.*
I think this may be a particular case of providing access to only a part of the interface. So far I've come up with a decorator approach:

```py
class _AccessorBase:
    __slots__ = ("owner")

    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.owner = owner

def _make_delegating_method(name, method=None):
    if method is None:
        method = name

    if isinstance(method, str):
        def delegating_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return getattr(self.owner, method)(*args, **kwargs)

    elif callable(method):
        def delegating_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return method(self.owner, *args, **kwargs)

    else:
        raise TypeError

    delegating_method.__name__ = name
    return delegating_method

def withaccessor(access_name, *method_names, **methods):
    class Accessor(_AccessorBase):
        __slots__ = ()

    for name in method_names:
        if name in methods:
            raise ValueError("name '{}' is given twice".format(name))
        methods[name] = name

    for name, method in methods.items():
        setattr(Accessor, name, _make_delegating_method(name, method))

    access_member_attr_name = "_" + access_name

    def access_method(self):
        return getattr(self, access_member_attr_name)

    access_method.__name__ = access_name

    def decor(cls):
        class C(cls):
            __doc__ = cls.__doc__
            __slots__ = access_member_attr_name

            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                setattr(self, access_member_attr_name, Accessor(self))
                return super(__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        C.__name__ = cls.__name__
        setattr(C, access_name, access_method)
        return C

    return decor

# Tests
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def sub(self):
        return self.a - self.b

    @withaccessor("view", "sum", product="prod", difference=sub)
    class C:
        __slots__ = ("a", "b")

        def __init__(self, a, b):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b

        def sum(self):
            return self.a + self.b

        def prod(self):
            return self.a * self.b

    o = C(2, 3)
    v = o.view()
    assert o.view() is v
    assert v.sum() == 5
    assert v.product() == 6
    assert v.difference() == -1
    o.a = 0
    assert v.sum() == 3
    assert v.product() == 0
    assert v.difference() == -3
```

Comment: @python_user no, absolutly not. A view is not a `list` or a `set`... it is a *view*... none of the `dict` view objects inherit from `dict` or `list` or `set`...

Comment: Basically, you just wrap your object, expose methods to do whatever you want, dont expose methods that mutate the object....

Comment: You can update view objects whenever the original object is updated using observer pattern. Register each view objects to original objects and then when original objects changed this will be notified.